# 3 JButtons not working to trigger 3 drawImages

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, jbutton, paint

I am trying to make a project with a border layout, 3 jbuttons, and the drawImage component of paint to create a stoplight that listens for button pushes and changes the images. I know my drawImages in the conditional statements work because if I take the if statement out the images appear fine, and I know the action listeners work because I tested each one with a joptionpane dialog box. However, in the current form, nothing happens at button push and I'm not sure why. Any help would be much appreciated, I am learning!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TrafficLight extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
//establishes panel, button, and boolean variables
 private JPanel pN, pS, pE, pW, pC;

 private JButton btnWait, btnGo, btnStop;

 private boolean redIlluminated = false , greenIlluminated = false , yellowIlluminated = false;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    TrafficLight frame = new TrafficLight();
    frame.setSize(750, 850);
    frame.createGUI();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

private void createGUI()
{
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container window = getContentPane();

    window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //custom colors
    Color slate=new Color(49, 58, 58);
    Color eggshell=new Color(230, 226, 222);
    Color easterPink=new Color(249, 170, 170);
    Color salmon=new Color(201, 80, 65);
    Color dusk=new Color(187, 185, 184);
    Color billiards=new Color(71, 88, 68);

    //custom fonts
    Font buttonFont = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 20);

    //sets up north jpanel 
    pN = new JPanel();
    pN.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(680,45));
    pN.setBackground(eggshell);
    window.add (pN, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    //button formatting
    //establishes go button, font, color, and click event, then adds it to pN panel
    btnGo = new JButton ("GO");
    btnGo.setFont(buttonFont);
    btnGo.setBackground(dusk);
     btnGo.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                //trigger condition change here to cause the paint event below
              greenIlluminated = true;
            }
        }
    );
    pN.add(btnGo);

    //establishes wait button, font, color, and click event, then adds it to pN panel
    btnWait = new JButton("WAIT"); 
    btnWait.setFont(buttonFont);
    btnWait.setBackground(dusk);
    btnWait.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
               //trigger condition change here to cause the paint event below 
              yellowIlluminated = true;
            }
        }
    );
    pN.add(btnWait);

    //establishes stop button, font, color, and click event, then adds it to pN panel
    btnStop = new JButton("STOP");
    btnStop.setFont(buttonFont);
    btnStop.setBackground(dusk);
    btnStop.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                //trigger condition change here to cause the paint event below
              redIlluminated = true;
            }
        }
    );
    pN.add(btnStop);

    //east jpanel for stoplight
    pE = new JPanel();
    pE.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(272,318));
    pE.setBackground(billiards);
    window.add (pE, BorderLayout.EAST);

    //west jpanel
    pW = new JPanel();
    pW.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(136,318));
    pW.setBackground(billiards);
    window.add (pW, BorderLayout.WEST);

    //center jpanel for car
    pC = new JPanel();
    pC.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(272,318));
    pC.setBackground(slate);
    window.add (pC, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //south jpanel
    pS = new JPanel();
    pS.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(680, 15));
    pS.setBackground(eggshell);
    window.add (pS, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent click) {


    }

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    //draws stoplight
    g.drawImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("red1.png")).getImage(), 460, 150, this);
    g.drawImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("green1.png")).getImage(), 460, 272, this);
    g.drawImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("yellow1.png")).getImage(), 460, 373, this);

    //draws car in center
    g.drawImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("car.png")).getImage(), 150, 600, this);

    //sets conditions to show images on button click based on boolean logic changed by buttons
    if (redIlluminated)
    {
        g.drawImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("red2.png")).getImage(), 460, 150, this);
    }

    else if (greenIlluminated)
    {
        g.drawImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("green2.png")).getImage(), 460, 272, this);
    }
    else if (yellowIlluminated)
    {
        g.drawImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("yellow2.png")).getImage(), 460, 373, this);
    }
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if still relevant to you, but just in case someone else stumbles upon this question...

The Swing Containers are not constantly listening for changes to its graphics, so when you do make a change you need to make sure to call `repaint()` so that the whole container is rendered again.

Adding that one method call inside the button's ActionListener would look like:

```
btnGo.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

          //trigger condition change here to cause the paint event below, I turn off the other flags so that the if clause in the paint method knows exactly what to paint 
          greenIlluminated = true;
          redIlluminated = false;
          yellowIlluminated = false;

          //This is the one method that triggers a call to the paint method you overrode
          repaint();
       }
});
```

And a similar change would need to be done to the other ActionListeners.

---

As a side note, you do not need to implement the ActionListener interface if you are going to use an object of an anonymous ActionListener class for your buttons.